# Conditionally execute custom powershell function/cmdlet after a built-in cmdlet is executed

Tags: powershell, automation, powercli

How do I set a custom function to run (when the module for said function is imported) each time that a specific built-in cmdlet is executed by a user?

e.g. If the user has the custom module loaded containing the custom function and runs the 'Get-Process' cmdlet then after the output is returned to the console 'Run-CustomFunction' is automatically called and executed.

-----------edit-----------

This is for a simple function that reads a .csv based on user input and constructs a cmd line with a regex and that executes a function with parameters from a module by a popular software vendor. Almost like a splat. It has a sister function that will help the user keep track of usage in the title bar of the console. What I am trying to solve for is that when a user types out the cmd line the title bar of the console is not updated. The .csv is constantly being manipulated so sometimes values that are needed are not available and the user has to manually key in the cmdlet and parameter values. When manually keyed in I still want the title bar to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility, though I'm not sure I'd actually recommend it:

In your custom module, re-define the cmdlet you want to modify so that it calls the original cmdlet, then does whatever extra stuff you want.  For example, here is how we could make Get-Service run after every call to Get-Process:

```
# Define a function called Get-Process
function Get-Process
{
    # Call original Get-Process cmdlet using 'modulename\cmdletname' syntax
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Process | Out-Host

    # Call get service (could be your own function instead)
    Get-Service
}
```

So, the output of the original Get-Process goes to the console and the result of Get-Service is returned from the function (and also goes to the console by default.  There are many reasons this is a very bad idea (e.g. it will break anything that expects the default behaviour from Get-Process), but you can try it if you want.

Comment: Interesting take. I like the idea and I appreciate the feedback. Do you think that maybe an alias with a global scope that calls the get-process function but also runs the custom function might work?